# Galaxy S9: How to backup everything? (Samsung Cloud or Google Backup)

Tags: samsung, backup

I have a new Galaxy S9 (first Android phone in my life) and the options on Settings to configure the backup is confusing.

I don't know what to choose, Samsung Cloud or Google Backup, both seems to backup the same thing, or not?.

I did a test, I used both (Samsung first, then Google) to do a backup and I restored the phone from these backups and I never got anything restore.

1. Samsung Cloud or Google Bakcup? what are the differences? Is very
   important to me to backup the Apps I have installed, the "Settings"
   configuration and the layout of my screen, ringtones, wallpaper, well, a backup of
   everything. (as an Iphone does)
2. How and where to configure to do a daily backup automatically?
3. How and where to enable Find my phone?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Hint for a new user here: many of our tags have wikis attached. May I suggest you to start with our [backup tag-wiki](/tags/backup/info) to get a raw idea first? It's last third has a few links on "full backups". Another hint: without root access, you won't be able to backup "everything". At best, you can come close to that goal. Also, I wouldn't rely too much on those "cloud backups". While the backups usually work, same cannot always be said about restore …

Comment: I don't know about Samsung Cloud, but Google isn't going to do the kind of backup you are looking for.  But peruse this list for something instead: https://www.androidauthority.com/best-android-backup-apps-and-other-ways-too-608014/

Comment: Go Titanium. If you can get TWRP, then Nandroid is also a solid choice